# Redirecting user to custom html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using AJAX to search from database and view the result on the front page.I am getting my output right and I want the user to be redirected to the profile page of the user he/she clicks on.Currently I am redirecting the user to the link http://localhost:3000/doc/:username. I am getting JSON from my API and want to view custom HTML for each username according to their data. What changes should I make.
Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/search',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "hidden";
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $(".username").remove();
    obj.forEach(function(element) {
      var url = "localhost:3000";
      url += "/doc/"
      url += element.username;
      $('.deneme').append("<a href=" + url + ">" + "<div class='username'>" + element.name + "</div>" + "</a>")
    }, this);
  }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  All you have stated is what you want, not what is not working.

Comment: it's being redirected to url as i mentioned. But at that url i have the json data from api. what i want to know is what should i do to redirect to the custom html page

Comment: Then I am very confused.  The logic that you have here appears to be related to generating the links to go to the secondary page.  But you say that this is working and ..... something.

Comment: it's not confusing at all.The link to secondary page is being generated but that page just contains JSON from the API.I want to generate a custom HTML page .I want to know what changes do i need to make in generating my url logic so that user will be directing to a html page with data from the api as well

Comment: Ok, so if the url you are going to contains just json, then it sounds like you need to forward the users to a different page, and that page needs to perform an ajax request to the current url you are using that returns json.  Then that page can use the json however it needs to.